# using memset() and memcpy() function

Tags: c++, memcpy, memset

```
// CPP Program to find all the common characters 
// in n strings 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

const int MAX_CHAR = 26; 

void commonCharacters(string str[], int n) 
{ 
  // primary array for common characters 
  // we assume all characters are seen before. 
  bool prim[MAX_CHAR] = {true}; 
  //memset(prim, true, sizeof(prim)); 

  // for each string 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

    // secondary array for common characters 
    // Initially marked false 
    bool sec[MAX_CHAR] = { false }; 

    // for every character of ith string 
    for (int j = 0; str[i][j]; j++) { 

      // if character is present in all 
      // strings before, mark it. 
      if (prim[str[i][j] - 'a']) 
        sec[str[i][j] - 'a'] = true; 
    } 

    // copy whole secondary array into primary 
    //memcpy(prim, sec, MAX_CHAR); 

    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
      prim[k] = sec[k];
  } 


  // displaying common characters 
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    if (prim[i]) 
      printf("%c ", i + 'a'); 
} 

// Driver's Code 
int main() 
{ 
  string str[] = { "geeksforgeeks", 
                   "gemkstones", 
                   "acknowledges", 
                   "aguelikes" }; 
  int n = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]); 
  commonCharacters(str, n); 
  return 0; 
}
```

We use two hash arrays of size 26 (for a-z, where 0 is a, and z is 25).
The approach is simple, if we have seen a character before we’ll mark it and if we haven’t then ignore the character because it is not a common one. 
why does this code not give desired output? Whereas if I use `memset(prim,true,sizeof(prim))` instead of `bool prim[MAX_CHAR] = {true};` for initialization and `memcpy(prim,sec,MAX_CHAR)` instead of `for(int k=0;k<n;k++) prim[k] = sec[k];` for copying the boolean array sec[] in prim[] it works just fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: As well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: As an aside, neither `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` or `using namespace std;` is considered good practice

Comment: Depending on your compiler and settings of it, you might be building the source in C++03 mode, in which case `std::string` might not contain a terminator. Always use the actual length of the string if iterating over indexes. Or better yet use iterators. Or even more better us a [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Regarding that commented out `memset` call, in the generic case use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead. And [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead of `memcpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning

```
bool prim[MAX_CHAR] = {true};
```

is not equivalent to `memset(prim, true, sizeof(prim));`

`MAX_CHAR` is 26, and you only give 1 value with `{true}`, so `prim[0]` is initialized with *true* and all the 25 next entries are initialized with 0 (*false*). *true* is not used up to the end of the array.

But

```
bool prim[MAX_CHAR] = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true }
```

initializes the 26 entries (if I count well)

Of course `memcpy(prim,sec,MAX_CHAR)` and `for(int k=0;k<n;k++) prim[k] = sec[k];` are not equivalent because *n* is the number of strings (4) and doesn't value `MAX_CHAR` (26)

Execution with your code :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution with *memset* or the 26 *true* in `{}`, and replacing `for(int k=0;k<n;k++)` by `for(int k=0; k<MAX_CHAR; k++)` :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
e g k s pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

A proposal from  François Andrieux (in a removed remark below) to remove the problem about the initialization of *prim* : reverse the boolean value in *prim*, so

```
void commonCharacters(string str[], int n) 
{ 
  // primary array for common characters 
  // we assume all characters are seen before. 
  // (false means seen before, reverse logic)
  bool prim[MAX_CHAR] = {false}; 

  // for each string 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

    // secondary array for common characters 
    // Initially marked false (standard logic)
    bool sec[MAX_CHAR] = { false }; 

    // for every character of ith string 
    for (int j = 0; str[i][j]; j++) { 

      // if character is present in all 
      // strings before, mark it. 
      if (!prim[str[i][j] - 'a']) 
        sec[str[i][j] - 'a'] = true; 
    } 

    // copy negation of whole secondary array into primary         
    for(int k=0; k<MAX_CHAR; k++)
      prim[k] = !sec[k];
  } 

  // displaying common characters 
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    if (!prim[i]) 
      printf("%c ", i + 'a'); 
}
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
e g k s pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

But the reverse logic for *prim* and the standard logic for *sec* can be confusing

Comment: Thank you for clarification on initialization mistake but still the expected output is `e g k s` **common characters**  So the answer for use of `memcpy(prim,sec,MAX_CHAR)` instead of `for(int k=0;k<n;k++) prim[k] = sec[k];` to copy the boolean array sec[] in prim[] still remains unanswered.

Comment: @Akshatmahla I edited my answer to speak about that and correct the code, but frankly _n_ valuing the number of strings (4) obviously `for(int k=0;k<n;k++) prim[k] = sec[k];` doesn't copy the full array (26 elements)